# Control if user used any $_GET[' ? ? '] URL method

Tags: php, get

I am trying to control if user type any GET url link, but I am able only if I specify $_GET request to redirect that URL does not exist..

For example when I type: https://someurl.com?id=2 I can control $_GET because I know "id" is called..

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo "URL DOES NOT EXIST";
  die();
}
```

So basically when user type any other instead of "id" the message will not be displayed...
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You want to know if $_GET is not empty but other key than 'id' ?

Comment: @Xenofexs Kinda yes, if that url does not exist show some message

Comment: So in your example when calling `https://someurl.com/id=2` the `$_GET` variable would be empty. So what should happen then? Please be more precise.

Comment: @DanielBürckner I am trying to control if any get url is typed to show message that url does not exist..  For example `https://someurl.com/id=2`, I can show message if user is typed `/id=` .. But what if user type `/idqwe=` (for example), then I can't controle it..

Comment: @Pablo: Usually a valid GET request looks like `https://someurl.com?id=2` and not `/id=2`. So I assume you are using some kind of URL rewrite.

Comment: yeah my mistake, I mean `?id=2` .. I did not used any kind of url rewrite..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just loop through your $_GET variable and check for its contents.

```
foreach ($_GET AS $Key => $Value) {
  echo "Set key: ".$Key;
  echo "Set value: ".$Value;
}
```

Or maybe just check if any $_GET variable was set:

```
if(!empty($_GET))
  echo "URL DOES NOT EXIST";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, [according to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151326/control-if-user-used-any-get-url-method/51152353#comment89287660_51151326), This is what you're trying to do:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    // If "id" is set and not empty, do:
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if (in_array($id, $arr)) {
        // If "id" is in array of available ids
        // Page exists
        echo "Hello World";
    } else {
        // Page does not exists
        echo "Page does not exists";
    }
} else {
    // Page does not exists
    echo "Page does not exists";
}
```

This will result:

```
index.php?id=1  // "Hello World"
index.php?id=27 // Page does not exists
index.php?id=   // Page does not exists
index.php       // Page does not exists
```

I do not recommend to use arrays for page id, use database (mysql/mariadb) instead

Comment: Yeah I know that, but what if user type something else instead of id ? For example `?idididid=2 ..`

Comment: you can check it using `in_array()` over all `GET` requests

Comment: you don't need to, let PHP do it :) run foreach loop on GET and then use in array